# Showing a Set is Orthonormal in $\mathbb{C}^N$

Tags: fourier-analysis

#### 1 Context

Fix natural $N > 0$ for $\mathbb{C}^N$. Let

$$
\omega := e^{2 \pi i / N}
$$

for

$$
e_n(k) := {1 \over \sqrt{N}} \omega^{kn} \text{ for } k \in \{0,1 \ldots, N-1\}
$$

#### 2 Problem

From a book on Harmonic Analysis:

> [image]

#### 3 Attempt

Let $l,j \in \{0,1, \ldots, N-1\}$ s.t. $l \ne j$.

$$
\langle e_l, e_j \rangle = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} {1 \over \sqrt{N}}\omega^{kl} \overline{{1 \over \sqrt{N}}\omega^{kj}} = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} {1 \over N}e^{2 \pi kl / N} e^{-2 \pi kj / N} = \ldots ? \ldots = 0
$$

Comment: Note that $e^{2\pi k i/N} e^{-2\pi j i/N} = e^{2\pi (k - j) i/N}$, another root of unity. If $k - j \neq 0$, then this root of unity is not $1$.

Comment: @TheoBendit: Does this mean that we could replace the constant ${1 \over \sqrt{N}}$ with any arbitrary constant $c$ in the definition of $e_n$, and still have that $\langle e_l, e_j \rangle = 0$ for $l \ne j$?

Comment: Yeah. You'd get an orthogonal basis, not an orthonormal one.